# How to format with newline included file in hta

Tags: vbscript, hta

When I load with the current script some csv file. Textarea not present the right format like in csv format:

1.csv:

```
text1
text2
```

Now 1.csv output:

```
text1 text2
```

Expected 1.csv output:

```
text1
text2
```

Actually textarea is not able to create newlines for some unknown reason for me.

The script:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <hta:application
     applicationname="MyHTA"    
     border="thick"
     borderstyle="normal"
     caption="My HTML Application"
     contextmenu="no"
     icon="myicon.ico"
     maximizebutton="no"
     minimizebutton="yes"
     navigable="no"
     scroll="yes"
     selection="no"
     showintaskbar="yes"
     singleinstance="yes"
     sysmenu="yes"
     version="1.0"
     windowstate="normal"
 >
 <script language="vbscript">  

Sub RunCommonDialog  
  Set objDialog = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")  
  objDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files|*.*" 
  objDialog.InitialDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop" 
  intResult = objDialog.ShowOpen  
  If intResult = 0 Then  
    Exit Sub  
  Else  
    CommonDialog.value = objDialog.FileName  
    CommonDialog_Span.innerHTML = objDialog.FileName  
    Const ForReading = 1
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objDialog.FileName, ForReading)
    contents = objTextFile.ReadAll
    objTextFile.Close
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objReadFile = Nothing
    PRE.innerHTML = contents
  End If  
End Sub  
 Sub reloadHTA()
 location.reload True
End Sub

</script>
<body> 
<input type="hidden" id="CommonDialog"><input type="button" onclick="RunCommonDialog" value="Browse..."><input class = "StdBtt Meta" type = "BUTTON" value = "Reset" onclick = "reloadHTA"><br>
<p>File: <span id="CommonDialog_Span"></span></p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="88" name="PRE" readonly="readonly">
</textarea> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a .hta that **concentrates** on your problem - e.g.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <hta:application id="t"></hta>
  <title>t</title>
  <script language="vbscript">
   Sub ol()
     MsgBox "ol"
     a = Array("line1", "line2")
     document.all.ta1.value = Join(a, vbCrLf)
     document.all.ta2.innerHTML = Join(a, vbCrLf)
   End Sub
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="ol">
  <textarea id="ta1" rows="4" cols="88"></textarea>
  <textarea id="ta2" rows="4" cols="88"></textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```

you'll see at a glance that your problem is caused by using `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`.

(BTW: You should use a validator (tidy, ...) on your .html)

**Update:**

Evidence:

[image: Evidence]

Comment: Great example Ekkehard, but that works only with arrays, when I try to load ReadAll from file, get error message like:
    Type mismatch 'Join'

Comment: @KalinBorisov - if you don't try to apply Join() to the result of .ReadAll() but assign it immediately to .value, you'll see that it 'works'.

Comment: Yes, I try and nothing happen

Comment: @KalinBorisov - I added a screenshot as evidence that assigning the result of .ReadAll() to .value 'works'. I hope this helps you to find out what is causing your script to fail - if not, please post minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Many thanks @Ekkehard.Horner, now I get your point very useful example.

Comment: Another thing is it possible that be done in exec I try something but don't get result:

`Public objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Sub CHECK()
strPattern = "stackoverflow.com"
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /c cat ""C:\mail.csv""|srt -u|cut -d "","" -f2|grep " + strPattern)
strText = ""
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = strText & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop
document.all.PRE.value = Join(strText, vbCrLf)
End Sub`

objShell.Exec output is:

Comment: Actually I find the solution again you help me very well.